# synchronize many Vectors together

Tags: java, vector, synchronized

I have a static Vector users, each user has one or more accounts, so for every User there is a Vector accounts. Users and Accounts has an unique id.
Adding a new User is simple: i got a static Vector and i can easily check the id of the last User and i can get the new id for the new User doing user.getId()+1.

After a new User is added a problem comes by adding a new Account. An Account id must be unique, so i have to check for the largest id contained in every user's Accounts Vector. Provided that many processes can add/remove users and Accounts, what is the best way to synchronize all the Account vectors and safely add/remove accounts?

Actually, a User is added as follows

```
public boolean addNewUser(User user)
{
    if(user!=null)
    {
        int id=getNewUserId();
        if(id!=-1)
        {
            user.setId(id);
            utenti.add(user);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

private int getNewUserId()
{
    User user=utenti.lastElement();
    if(user!=null)
        return user.getId()+1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is this some legacy code you are working on? If not, then please avoid using `Vector` in the first place.

Comment: Please show us some code snippet, showing how are you currently adding users and accounts.

Comment: What should i use instead on Vector? And why? Unfortunately i've still not made any function, i'll code it when i have a solution ;)

Comment: All this is stored in memory?

Comment: yes all stored in memory, but the persistence is backed by a DB

Comment: You already have a race condition in the code that you posted. There may be *two* users created with the *same* ID. You should probably describe more clearly how accounts are added (or how they should be added, maybe again with an "unsafe" code snippet). Maybe you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html for the ID generation, but until now, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the id, I recommend using a long value that you increment all the time (regadless of accounts being deleted).

Synchronizing will be harder and depends on what you want to do.
An easy rule would be, if you have a list object, use a synchronized block whenever you access it (read or write):

```
synchronized(myList) {
    //update the list, do whatever you like, there is no concurrent modification
}
```

Depending on your exact usage, there might be better ways, but this should work.

Comment: as far as i know, only primitives can be synchronized. Is that wrong? Please note that every users.elementAt(i) has a Account Vector inside.

Comment: @mark Only objects can be synchronized. Only ONE synchronized block for a certain object can be active at any given time, which is why it's nice to use it on a list.

Comment: Objects? Can you please provide me some official docs about it?

Comment: Thank you, it is a very good resource solving my doubts about synchronization. Unluckily here i should synchronize a group of vectors<Account>

Comment: @mark That's no problem. You could even create an empty Object to synchronize on it. The point is that the codes cannot be executed at the same time, so you're safe. You just need an indicator variable like isEditingTheList that you synchronize on.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way, but you could make an int and then go through the sizes of every list of accounts for every user.

```
int id = 0;
for (User user : AllUsers) {
    id += user.listOfAccounts.size();
}
```

Now your id will be the last id. Simply add 1 when you create a new account.

Note that there will be problems if it's possible to delete accounts.